# Error "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, npgsql

I'm working with Npgsql and Entity Framework. I'm trying to make new one migration but I have the error from the question title. I already have tried example from [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-application-services).

So, my code is:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LalalaDb")));
    }
}
```

Where is the problem? How I can make a migration?

#### Update

This is my `ApplicationDbContext.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    // and more DbSets are here ... 

    public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("LalalaDb");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("EntityFrameworkProject"));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the implementation of the `ApplicationDbContext` class?

Comment: @p4r1 Could you check my update?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [documentation for building your own DbContext class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) and the [documentation for DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) for some additional considerations/best practices.

First thing I noticed is that your context class does not include a parameterless constructor or a constructor that takes in a `DbContextOptions<T>` instance, which is likely the cause for why migrations are not able to be created.

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    // and more DbSets are here ... 

    public ApplicationDbContext() : base()
    { }

    public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("LalalaDb");
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("EntityFrameworkProject"));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue!
So, I just have `Class library` project. In the project I have:

- `ApplicationDbContext.cs` (like in the question)
- Folder with migrations.

And I just put `Program.cs` file with the following content:

```
public class Program
{
    public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envName}.json")
                .Build();
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("LalalalDb");
            builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
            return new ApplicationDbContext(configuration);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally,

`$ dotnet ef migrations add Lalalalalal` - works!

P.S. Don't forget about `appsettings.<Your ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT>.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem in my project was that I had as StartUp Project the data layer. So I changed it to the project where the StartUp class was located and that was enough.